# How to remove and put again group of divs

Tags: javascript, html

Found a problem with turning on/off background script
I have two divs

```
<div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back" id="par_back">
    <div  id="back">
        <canvas></canvas> 
        <canvas></canvas>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

and function that will remove this code for lower resourses using and paste it again

```
function Eco() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("eco");
  var script = document.getElementById("back");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
      script.parentNode.removeChild(script);  
  } else {
      script.innerHTML = "<div  id="back"><canvas></canvas><canvas></canvas><script src="js/index.js"></script></div>";
  }
}
```

but innerHTML doesn't works for divs(

Comment: Take a look at your quotes in `script.innerHTML = "<div  id="back"><canvas></canvas><canvas></canvas><script src="js/index.js"></script></div>";`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the script.innerHTML line has the issue. You'll either need to escape the double quotes within the string, or use single quotes to surround it. Try one of these:

Escaping:

```
script.innerHTML = "<div id=\"back\"><canvas></canvas><canvas></canvas><script src=\"js/index.js\"></script></div>";
```

Single quotes:

```
script.innerHTML = '<div id="back"><canvas></canvas><canvas></canvas><script src="js/index.js"></script></div>';
```